# installing packages from a repo

Tags: python

I'm trying to install Python packages that have been reviewed and approved from a trusted source.

The packages have filenames like this: `numpy-1.21.5-py39h6c91a56_3.tar.bz2`
and they are housed at this site: https://artifactory.faa.gov/ui/native/conda-remote/linux-64/

How do I install these packages? I'm used to using pip and have no idea what to do here.

I use Spyder on a Windows machine. I'm not a computer scientist and taught myself Python using Youtube and Stack Overflow. I'd appreciate a kindergarten simple explanation.

Comment: on Linux you could unpack using `tar -xf numpy-1.21.5-py39h6c91a56_3.tar.bz2` and it may have file `setup.py` which should run as `python setup.py build` and later `python setup.py install`. But `numpy` may use code in C/C++ so it may need C/C++ compiler and file `Python.h` with C/C++ headers. And this can make big problem on Windows. Better install modules with `pip` (or eventually using `conda`)

Comment: The website does not seem to work, so we can't say anything about that. In general: RTFM. There is no standard for installing (arbitrary) software packages. For this example, open the archive, check for a README.txt, INSTALL.txt or similar file. Usually installation instructions are available in the [online manual](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/building.html) as well. However, since you are using custom modules, these instructions may or may not apply.